# Include long options without short options for help and version

Tags: rust, clap

I would like to include `--help` and `--version` long options without the `-h` and `-V` short options. Is this possible?

I'm using clap with yaml. The closest I've been able to come up with is to use hidden (unused) args that mask the short options.

```
# main.rs
use clap::{load_yaml, App};
fn main() {
  let y = load_yaml!("cli.yaml");
  let m = App::from_yaml(y).get_matches();
  println!("_help {}", m.is_present("_help"));
  println!("_version {}", m.is_present("_version"));
}
```

```
# Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "app"
version = "0.0.1"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
clap = {version = "~2.33.0", features = ["yaml"]}
```

```
# cli.yaml
name: app
version: 0.0.1
args:
  - opt: { short: "o", long: "opt" }
  - _help: { short: "h", hidden: true }
  - _version: { short: "V", hidden: true }
```

```
$ cargo -q run -- --help
app 0.0.1

USAGE:
    app [FLAGS]

FLAGS:
        --help       Prints help information
    -o, --opt        
        --version    Prints version information

$ cargo -q run -- -h    
_help true
_version false
$ cargo -q run -- -o
_help false
_version false
$ cargo -q run -- -V
_help false
_version true
$ cargo -q run -- -x
error: Found argument '-x' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    app [FLAGS]

For more information try --help
```

This doesn't feel like a very clean approach. Is there another/better way?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want `-h` to result in `"Found argument '-h' which wasn't expected, ..."`, right?

Comment: @vallentin, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clap is designed more towards creating an args parser. So there aren't really that much functionality for getting and removing existing arguments.

*If you simply want to rename `"-h"` to e.g. `"-?"`, then you can do that with [`help_short("-?")`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.3/clap/struct.App.html#method.help_short) (see also [`version_short()`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.3/clap/struct.App.html#method.version_short).)*

However, there are ways to work around it.

---

Assuming you're using e.g. `clap = "2.33"`. Then similarly to what you're already doing, you can override/replace the `help` and `version` args, and in that way "remove" the short versions. *(For brevity, I'll only include examples for `help`.)*

You can of course keep it in `cli.yaml` if you want, but I'll add it to `main.rs`. In short, you want to add a new `"help"` arg and only give it a `long` version. It's important that you include `help("Prints help information")` as this is replacing the existing `help` arg, so if you don't it won't have the default help message for `--help`.

The downside to overring `"help"` is that you'd need to handle `print_help()` yourself.

```rust
use clap::{load_yaml, App, Arg};

fn main() {
    let y = load_yaml!("cli.yaml");
    let mut app = App::from_yaml(y)
        .arg(
            Arg::with_name("help")
                .long("help")
                .help("Prints help information"),
        );

    let m = app.clone().get_matches();

    if m.is_present("help") {
        app.print_help().unwrap();
        // std::process::exit(0);
        // or just
        return;
    }
}
```

---

However, if you're using [`clap = "3.0.0-beta.2"`](https://crates.io/crates/clap/3.0.0-beta.2) then that simplifies things, with the introduction of [`mut_arg()`](https://docs.rs/clap/3.0.0-beta.2/clap/struct.App.html#method.mut_arg). Because that allows us to mutate *the* argument. Thereby, we no longer need to call `print_help()` ourselves.

```rust
use clap::{load_yaml, App, Arg};

fn main() {
    let y = load_yaml!("cli.yaml");
    let m = App::from(y)
        .mut_arg("help", |h| {
            Arg::new("help")
                .long("help")
                .about("Prints help information")
        })
        .get_matches();
}
```

*Note that `App::from_yaml()` is now `App::from()`, while `Arg::with_name()` has become `Arg::new()`, and `help()` is now `about()`.*

Comment: Perfect! Info on current stable and new versions was very helpful. Exact info I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like this answer is now thoroughly obsolete; clap has had two major versions since it was posted, and none of the APIs involved still exist. Does anyone have any info on how to do this in v4?